# How would I model 2 different vendors on an online marketplace selling the same product; i.e. with the same productID?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

Take Ebay for example. Ebay has an unlimited about of vendors. However, what if two vendors were to sell the same product. That product would have the same productID right? How would I go about modelling this using RDF(s) or OWL?

Comment: "about" -> "amount" ?

Answer (score 1):

In OWL you can have a `Product` class which is a subclass of a DataProperty `hasID some string`. Then you define that `Product hasKey hasID`. If you now have 2 individuals of type `Product` with the same value for `hasID`, the reasoner will infer that the 2 individuals are the same individuals. Here is the example ontology:

```
Datatype: xsd:string

DataProperty: hasID
    Range: xsd:string

Class: Product
    SubClassOf: hasID some xsd:string
    HasKey: hasID

Individual: productA
    Types: Product
    Facts: hasID  "\"123\""^^xsd:string

Individual: productB
    Types: Product
    Facts:  hasID  "\"123\""^^xsd:string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find same items from different vendors using ProductId.

eBay don't have option to list from similar items in existing catalog. Amazon has such listing option, so you can find similar items from different vendors using ASIN (ProductId)

To get this, you can use UPC (from item specifics) or Title match